# Angular cli how to access local html file?

Tags: angular-cli

I'm working with angular cli 1.6.5
and I'm trying to get an html file via get method

I added the html file in `src/assets/result/file.html`
and I added in `.angular-cli.json` the result folder

```
"assets": [
   "assets",
   "result"
  ],
```

now in my component I try this

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.http.get('assets/result/file.html').subscribe((res) => {
  console.log(res);
 });
}
```

am I missing something?

What I'm trying to achieve:
I build npm package that run on my infra component and extract example of html code.
for example

#### infra component

```
 /**
 *  @example
 *  <mgmt-ui-input
 *    [showIconX]="true"
 *    [showIconV]="true"
 *    (close)="onClose($event)"
 *  >
 *    <input type="text">
 *  </mgmt-ui-input>
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'mgmt-ui-input',
  templateUrl: './ui-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ui-input.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

#### the result of the npm package is file.html

```
 <mgmt-ui-input
     [showIconX]="true"
     [showIconV]="true"
     (close)="onClose($event)"
   >
     <input type="text">
   </mgmt-ui-input>
```

now in my project there is page with all infra demo just like angular material. in order to automatic process I want to display in ace editor the html

the result will look
[image]

Comment: Could you expand a bit on what you're trying to *achieve* with this? It seems a bit odd to be handling HTML within an SPA like that.

Comment: I build npm package that run on my infra component and extract documentation to html file. now I have demo page with ace editor that I want to inject the html per demo

Comment: Please [edit] to explain what you're trying to achieve. Could you not serve that file directly from the web server, rather than trying to sideload it via Angular, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found what I missed.

HttpClient calls response map to JSON internally.

in order to read the full response need to set the options {observe: 'response'}

more about it I found here 
https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response